# subtract dates from two files for same process

Tags: regular-expression

I have initiated 50 processes and in one file "say start_time", I have stored when process was started and in another file "say end_time", I have stored when process finished.
files are like below -

```
Start time - 
Start time for Process A : 15/09/26 21:02:13
Start time for Process B : 15/09/26 20:06:14
Start time for Process C : 15/09/26 13:20:52
Start time for Process D : 15/09/26 11:23:46

End time file 
End time for Process B : 15/09/26 21:13:38
End time for Process D : 15/09/26 12:31:29
End time for Process A : 15/09/26 22:06:11
End time for Process C : 15/09/26 12:17:10
```

Now I want to calculate execution time for each process
like Process A : 10 mins
Process B : 5 mins
etc.

Comment: In start_end and end_time file, is each process time entry starts at new line ??

Comment: I would suggest adding `%s` (seconds since the epoch, 1970-01-01 00:00:00) immediately after each human readable date (or instead of human readable if they'll never be read by a human).  then calculation is a simple subtraction of end time in secs - start time in secs.

Comment: Are the `Start time -` and `End time file` lines actually in the files?

Answer (score 0):

I agree with [cas](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/7696/cas)' comment above re proper logfile date to avoid it future reformatting as below

```
awk '
/:/{
    d=$(NF-1)
    gsub("/","",d)
    "date +%s -d \""d" "$NF"\"" | getline m
    if(/Start/)
        D[$5]=-m
    else
        D[$5]+=m
END{
    for(i in D)
        print "Process", i, "time :", D[i], "sec"
}' file
```

To save the ending order of processes just change the end of script to:

```
…       D[$5]=-m
    else
        print "Process", $5, "time :", D[$5] + m
}' file
```